# IIS 7.5 - Remove the pipe character from usernames for virtual hosts

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5, anonymous

Currently I have a setup with a virtual FTP site in IIS 7.5 that requires the following authentication details for the anonymous account:

```
Host: ftp.mydomain.com
User: ftp.mydomain.com|anonymous
Pass: <none>
```

I have multiple FTP accounts setup on this same server. I know that this means I need to specify the domain in the username to let IIS know what I need site to authenticate against, but is it possible to make the username only be `anonymous`? Would I have to create a user by that name in the windows users and groups area to be and specifically link it there?

Answer (score 1):

As you are probably aware, unlike HTTP, FTP has no equivalent of HTTP host headers. Different FTP server implementations that allow multiple FTP sites to use the same IP address (using FTP Virtual Host Names in the case of IIS FTP) require that you specify the site being authenticated to in the username.

If you need to have a site where you want to make anonymous access simple and dispense with the hostname in the username then you'll need to put that site on its own dedicated IP address.